# MariaDb via Puppet and Vagrant

Tags: mysql, virtualbox, vagrant, puppet, mariadb

I have a task to create a box with some configuration(Apache, php etc) and with MariaDb 10.0. But in this site https://puphpet.com/ we have only MySQL and searching I have found this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/puppet-and-mariadb/, but there are nothing about MariaDb 10.0. Any advices ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the MariaDB puppet modules seem to be out of date for installing version 10 and later, so your best bet is to roll up your sleeves and do it yourself.

Basically you'll need to configure a [yumrepo](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#yumrepo) for [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/installing-mariadb-with-yum/). A list of repos can be found at http://yum.mariadb.org/.

Then install the [package](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/latest/type.html#package) with the version you want.

Hope this helps you get started!